# How to get each post's id on my page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to send post id in js. I can send the first post id but how can I  send  each post's id. inspect element looks like this

```
<div  data-id="post_1"></div>
<div  data-id="post_2"></div>
<div  data-id="post_3"></div>


<script type="text/javascript" >
 function ajax(){

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){

    document.querySelector('[data-id=post_1]').innerHTML = req.responseText;
    } 
    }
    req.open('GET','chat.php?id=1>',true); 
    req.send();

    }
    setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000);


</script>
```

here is the code

```
<div  data-id="post_<?php echo $post_id;?>"></div>



<script type="text/javascript" >
 function ajax(){

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){

    document.querySelector('[data-id=post_<?=$post_id?>]').innerHTML = req.responseText;
    } 
    }
    req.open('GET','chat.php?id=<?=$post_id?>',true); 
    req.send();

    }
    setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000);


</script>
```

All the posts are on the same page. But I am able to get only one post's id. How can I get id  `post_2` and `post_3`  in js?

The js shows comment for each post. Only first post is showing comments cause js is getting only the first post's id. Rest are not showing anything.

How can I do the same for every post ?

Comment: this is not jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelector` will never give you more than 1 element. If you need all elements that satisfy your query, use `querySelectorAll`.

Using `PHP` in your `JS` code means that it will only ever use 1 `post_id`

Easiest way to do this would be to add a `class` or other `data-attribute` to your divs:

```
<div data-type="post" data-id="1">a</div>
<div data-type="post" data-id="3">b</div>
<div data-type="post" data-id="2">c</div>
```

You can use the new `attribute` to get them all and iterate over them.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-type="post"]')
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var postId = elements[i].getAttribute('data-id')
  // do ajax stuff
  // ... then
  elements[i].innerHTML = 'ajax response'
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w6kazkm1/4/

edit: Misunderstood your question. Answer is now updated.